# How do I convert a String representation of time into Unix time?

Tags: java, android, time

I need to convert timestamps of the form `yy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss` to a `long` that represents Unix time. Is there a class in Java's standard library that allows me to do this very easily? Or will I have to code the conversion algorithm myself?

I'm doing this on Android API level 7, in case that environment cuts off some of the necessary Java libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to parse your timestamp ([`String.split()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) may prove useful here) to create a [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html). From here you can call [`Calandar.getTimeInMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) to get the UTC time.

Comment: So, just to make sure, do I create this Calendar object by using `new Calendar()`, and then calling `set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)`?

Comment: Never mind. I found out that `Calendar` is an abstract class, so I resorted to using a `GregorianCalendar` instead.

Comment: `Calendar` has a static method `getInstance()`. After obtaining an instance of a `Calendar` you could use the various `set()` methods to set your date. Or you could use a `GregorianCalendar`. Cheers